# Converting Keras model with one ragged input to Tensorflow Lite results in multiple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I've reproduced this in tensorflow==2.8.0 and 2.11.0. When I build a model using the Keras API with one ragged input and then convert it to a TF lite model as below I can see in the `tf.lite.Interpreter` that my input has become two inputs, one of the original shape and dtype and one with dtype int32 and shape 1. It also loses the `input_1` name it's given. It's causing a problem using the tflite model for inference because it has more inputs than expected. My questions are:

1. Is there any way to avoid this input-splitting behavior while retaining the ragged functionality?
2. If not, what is meant to go into the extra input? Is it the size of the ragged input?

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape=[None, 4],
    dtype=tf.float32,
    ragged=True,
    name="input_1",
)
output_layer = tf.reduce_mean(input_layer, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    inputs=input_layer,
    outputs=output_layer,
)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS,  # enable TensorFlow ops
]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open("test_model.tflite", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="test_model.tflite")
print(len(interpreter.get_input_details()))

>>> 2

print(interpreter.get_input_details())

>>> [{'name': 'serving_default_args_0:0',
  'index': 0,
  'shape': array([1, 4], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([-1,  4], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'serving_default_args_0_1:0',
  'index': 1,
  'shape': array([1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([-1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.int64,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```